# Identify function of cluster with high identity of genes

Tags: mycology

Let's say there is a secondary metabolites biosynthesis cluster in fungi A.
and I just found out a gene B(identitiy>=50% with nrps gene located in the cluster) from fungi B and also found that gene B is located in some gene cluster in fungi B genome. My question is, with these two proofs can I say the gene cluster including gene B is doing same function with a secondary metabolites biosynthesis cluster in fungi A?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Take the tour and read the help on asking questions. 1. Your "let's say" suggests that this is a homework question. Is it? 2. you need to set out the information (evidence, not proof in English) clearly, point by point. What does "nrps gene" mean? When you say there is a gene cluster in gene B, what is your evidence this is a "cluster"? You only mention geneB, which I presume is related to one of the genes in fungus A (fungi is plural). Do you know anything about the other genes in fungus B? 3. without demonstration of function you can only talk abut likelihood.